# Number of positive integers that cannot be expressed as $ax+by$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove that there are exactly

$$\displaystyle{\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}}$$

positive integers that *cannot* be expressed in the form

$$ax\hspace{2pt}+\hspace{2pt}by$$

where $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integers, and $a, b$ are positive integers such that $\gcd(a,b) =1$.

Comment: Note that the question requires $ax+by$ to be positive and $x,y$ to be nonnegative.

Comment: @anon $x,y$ must be non-negative.

Comment: In other words, if you have 3-coins and 5-cent coins, there are exactly four positive numbers of cents that you can't pay.  (Apparently 1, 2, 4, and 7.)

Comment: @MartinArgerami : What must be positive is $a$ and $b$, not $ax+by$.  In other words, the denominations of the coins are positive, but the number of coins of a particular denomination used in a particular payment may be zero.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: since zero is not a positive integer, it shouldn't be counted (i.e. $x=y=0$ is not allowed, as per the question): "Prove that there are exactly ... **positive integers** that cannot be expressed... "

Comment: Please don't yell. Using all caps is considered yelling.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : $x=0$ and $y=0$ are indeed allowed.  Read the question.  It said $a$ and $b$ are positive and $x$ and $y$ are _non-negative_.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I fail to see your point. Read the question. It says *positive integers* that cannot be expressed... Since $0$ *can* be expressed as $ax+by$, its presence or absence is irrelevant, as it is not one of the numbers that should be counted. So it's either the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{ax+by: x,y \text{ non-negative integers not both null}\}$, or the cardinality of $(\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\})\setminus\{ax+by: x,y \text{ non-negative integers}\}$: it's the same.

Answer (score 3):

Hints: Prove

If $ax+by=c$, and $ax'+by'=c$, then $b$ divides $x-x'$, and $a$ divides $y-y'$, and $(x-x')/b=(y'-y)/a$.

$n$ can be expressed if and only if $((a-1)(b-1)/2)-1-n$ can't.

Comment: I could prove that $$ab \hspace{2pt}-\hspace{2pt}a\hspace{2pt}-\hspace{2pt}b$$ is the largest integer which cannot be expressed as $$ax\hspace{2pt}+\hspace{2pt}by$$  But cannot do the second part (I still don't understand Gerry's Hint)

Comment: (1) If you want me to see your comment, you have to put @Gerry in it. (2) I gave two hints. Which one don't you understand?

Answer (score 3):

Call an integer *bad* if it cannot be represented as an integer combination of $a$ and $b$ with non-negative coefficients. There are $(a-1)(b-1)$ non-negative integers less than $(a-1)(b-1)$, and you know that all of the bad integers are among them. Take a look at a simple example. Suppose that $a=4$ and $b=7$, so that the bad integers must lie between $0$ and $17$ inclusive.

$$\begin{array}{r|c}
\text{Good}:&0&16&15&14&4&12&11&7&8\\ \hline
\text{Bad}:&17&1&2&3&13&5&6&10&9
\end{array}$$

Notice that the numbers in each column add up to $17=(a-1)(b-1)-1$. A little experimentation will suggest that this is a general phenomenon: if $B=(a-1)(b-1)-1$ is the largest bad integer, and $0\le n\le B$, then exactly one of $n$ and $B-n$ is bad. If you can prove this, you’ll have as an immediate consequence that $\frac12(B+1)=\frac12(a-1)(b-1)$ integers are bad.

It’s easy to see that $n$ and $B-n$ cannot both be good: that would make $B$ good. Thus, you want to show that they also cannot both be bad. For this you’ll probably want to use what you know about the general solution to the Diophantine equation $c=ax+by$. If you get stuck, take a look at the proof of Lemma 3 in [this paper](http://math.pugetsound.edu/%7Emspivey/FrobFinal.pdf) by Mike Spivey; it isn’t exactly what you want, but it’s very close and should give you the ideas that you need to complete the argument.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I like your explanation.

Comment: I think I understand Aryabhata's statement. Originally I posted the question correctly, someone pointed out it should be be positive not non-negative. Therefore I edited the question back to the correct form.  I understand there is more than one way to solve a Mathematical problem, but some like one approach and some would prefer other ways.  I like Brian's suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that any number $\ge (a-1)(b-1)$ is representable.

The number of numbers $c$ such that $0 \lt c \lt ab$ which are representable correspond exactly to the number of lattice points in the region

$ax + by \lt ab$, $x \ge 0$, $y \ge 0$

This is because if $ax + by = ax' + by'$, then $x-x'$ is divisible by $b$, which cannot happen in the region, so two lattice points represent different numbers (and vice-versa).

A straigthforward counting argument now gives what you seek. Note, you would need to do some subtraction to get the count of numbers that are *not* representable, since the above lattice points count the numbers that are representable.

Comment: You are not reading the question properly, it is not saying $$\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}$$ to be represented.  It says THERE ARE EXACTLY  $$\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{2}$$ positive integers that cannot be represented as $$ax+by$$ form

Comment: @Sam: I think I am reading it properly (I consider NOT REPRESENTED only). What mistake did you find?

Comment: Sorry Aryabhata.

Comment: @Sam: You don't have to apologize!